# How Do I Test That My Swagger Documentation Is Valid?

Tags: java, unit-testing, swagger-ui, springfox

It is very easy for Swagger annotations to drift away from the actual code.

E.g.

I could change the return from `Response.ok` to `Response.created` and easily forget to update the annotations from 200 to 201.

Or I could change what is valid as null or not null and the end user will get confusing rejection messages even though their payload matches exactly what the documentation says.

How do I test that my swagger documentation matches what my code is doing?

- A test that uses selenium and phantomjs to parse the swagger-ui web page?
- Reflection to parse the annotations?
- Get the generated swagger.json and parse it?
- Something else?

Unfortunately I can't switch to Spring REST Docs.

Comment: With all respect and understanding to your willingness to automate the verification of the documentation, I wonder if this isn't the case for rigorous code reviews rather than automated testing. I can imagine the cost of implementing a bulletproof testing harness over Swagger docs might be pretty high. Regards,

Comment: Its not about code review. Its about ensuring that my documentation matches my code. Documentation loses its value if it is incorrect.

Comment: I understood it. Re-read my comment, please. You have two options (verify automatically or review it by a human) and in this case, I suggest you should go with the latter.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I am looking to do the former though and verify it automatically using code.

Comment: @TomekKaczanowski Having someone reviewing the API documentation is a must - no argue about that, however automation is still required to verify the documentation matches the code. Code tends to change frequently, and code reviewers might forget to verify that the respective document has been updated. Automation gives you the ability to refactor the code without worrying that your API documentation might become outdated, very similar to regular unit-tests that allow you to refactor your code with greater confidence. I've seen many cases of outdated API docs that lead to unhappy customers.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the [following library](https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/swagger-request-validator/src/master/) which contains a couple of projects that deal with API validation. I think the one you're looking for is called "swagger-request-validator-mockmvc", but you might find the other libraries useful as well.
Good luck.